# Reorganize array to separate arrays with associsated keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which I'm getting from HTML form and I need it to change it to a desired way. I have tried many things but I can't achieve what I want.

HTML form:

```
<form class="posalji_podatke" name="posalji_podatke[]" method="post" action="store_projection.php">
<tr>
   <td><div class="article_no"> <input type="hidden" class="article_no" name="freez[article_no][]" value="'.$value['article_no'].'"> '.$value['article_no'].'</div></td>
   <td>'.$naziv.'</td>
   <td><div class="plan_kolicina"> <input type="hidden" class="planska_kolicina" name="freez[plan_kolicina][]" value="'.$plan_kolicina.'"> '.$plan_kolicina.'</div></td>
   <td><div class="plan_ruc"> <input type="hidden" class="planska_ruc" name="freez[plan_ruc][]" value="'.$plan_ruc.'"> '.myNumberFormat($plan_ruc).'</div> kn</td>
   <td>'.myNumberFormat($plan_ruc_per).' %</td>
   <td><div class="prodana_kol"> <input type="hidden" class="stvarna_kolicina" name="freez[stvarna_kolicina][]" value="'.$kolicina.'"> '.$kolicina.'</div></td>
   <td><div class="prodani_ruc"> <input type="hidden" class="stvarni_ruc" name="freez[stvarni_ruc][]" value="'.$realizacija_ruc.'"> '.myNumberFormat($realizacija_ruc).'</div> kn</td>
   <td>'.myNumberFormat($realizacija_ruc_per).' %</td>
```

Array I'm getting from that form is:

```
Array (
[freez] => Array
    (
        [article_no] => Array
            (
                [0] => 967 86 19-03
                [1] => 967 10 84-01
                [2] => 967 86 18-14
                [3] => 967 78 85-35
                [4] => 967 15 69-75
                [5] => 967 69 06-35
                [6] => 966 45 19-68
                [7] => 966 42 83-18
                [8] => 966 73 39-88
                [9] => 967 69 08-35
                [10] => 966 01 00-66
                [11] => 965 96 81-38
                [12] => 966 73 31-38
                [13] => 965 06 06-20
                [14] => 966 99 72-12
                [15] => 967 28 75-12
                [16] => 967 20 57-16
                [17] => 967 32 96-01
                [18] => 967 67 64-01
                [19] => 970 45 74-01
                [20] => 967 67 78-01
                [21] => 967 67 80-01
                [22] => 967 90 79-01
                [23] => 967 90 81-01
                [24] => 966 77 97-01
                [25] => 952 71 57-52
                [26] => 967 19 36-01
                [27] => 966 77 68-01
                [28] => 966 77 71-01
                [29] => 967 14 83-02
                [30] => 966 77 99-01
                [31] => 966 62 89-01
                [32] => 966 62 87-01
                [33] => 966 01 59-01
                [34] => 966 78 00-02
                [35] => 966 62 90-01
                [36] => 966 78 02-01
                [37] => 967 17 65-01
                [38] => 966 53 24-01
                [39] => 967 65 84-01
                [40] => 966 78 77-01
                [41] => 952 71 56-45
                [42] => 967 28 42-01
                [43] => 966 62 96-01
                [44] => 967 07 98-01
                [45] => 967 68 21-01
                [46] => 967 05 42-01
                [47] => 967 63 73-01
                [48] => 967 10 10-01
                [49] => 964 95 40-03
                [50] => 967 63 67-01
                [51] => 967 63 68-01
                [52] => 967 98 87-01
                [53] => 967 98 86-01
                [54] => 967 06 93-01
                [55] => 967 98 88-01
                [56] => 970 45 01-01
                [57] => 967 34 32-02
                [58] => 970 44 90-01
                [59] => 960 41 04-31
                [60] => 960 41 04-21
                [61] => 960 51 01-89
                [62] => 960 51 01-90
                [63] => 960 41 04-36
                [64] => 960 51 01-93
                [65] => 967 84 69-01
                [66] => 967 84 71-01
                [67] => 967 84 75-01
                [68] => 967 64 84-01
                [69] => 967 62 87-02
                [70] => 967 62 88-02
                [71] => 967 84 79-01
                [72] => 967 84 78-01
                [73] => 967 84 80-02
                [74] => 967 66 97-02
                [75] => 967 66 57-02
                [76] => 967 09 82-02
                [77] => 967 89 38-14
                [78] => 967 89 39-12
                [79] => 967 86 41-14
                [80] => 967 86 37-14
                [81] => 967 88 48-10
                [82] => 967 09 83-02
                [83] => 967 91 57-02
                [84] => 967 97 12-01
                [85] => 967 09 88-02
                [86] => 967 91 61-11
                [87] => 967 91 62-02
                [88] => 967 85 06-01
                [89] => 967 91 55-02
                [90] => 967 62 84-01
                [91] => 967 86 23-01
                [92] => 967 64 54-16
                [93] => 967 97 40-16
                [94] => 967 67 29-16
                [95] => 967 85 27-16
                [96] => 967 67 31-16
                [97] => 967 85 28-16
                [98] => 967 85 30-16
                [99] => 967 66 21-16
                [100] => 967 65 02-16) 
         [plan_kolicina] => Array
            (
                [0] => 750
                [1] => 380
                [2] => 730
                [3] => 700
                [4] => 800
                [5] => 1150
                [6] => 300
                [7] => 1050
                [8] => 50
                [9] => 100
                [10] => 65
                [11] => 135
                [12] => 75
                [13] => 50
                [14] => 58
                [15] => 21
                [16] => 48
                [17] => 38
                [18] => 80
                [19] => 75
                [20] => 38
                [21] => 20
                [22] => 55
                [23] => 24
                [24] => 270
                [25] => 700
                [26] => 105
                [27] => 1350
                [28] => 170
                [29] => 70
                [30] => 600
                [31] => 700
                [32] => 45
                [33] => 150
                [34] => 190
                [35] => 50
                [36] => 70
                [37] => 3
                [38] => 130
                [39] => 40
                [40] => 2
                [41] => 310
                [42] => 115
                [43] => 18
                [44] => 7
                [45] => 15
                [46] => 8
                [47] => 17
                [48] => 10
                [49] => 19
                [50] => 260
                [51] => 400
                [52] => 480
                [53] => 440
                [54] => 76
                [55] => 360
                [56] => 278
                [57] => 3
                [58] => 60
                [59] => 204
                [60] => 86
                [61] => 70
                [62] => 25
                [63] => 22
                [64] => 20
                [65] => 150
                [66] => 20
                [67] => 5
                [68] => 5
                [69] => 2
                [70] => 7
                [71] => 9
                [72] => 1
                [73] => 1
                [74] => 5
                [75] => 10
                [76] => 25
                [77] => 17
                [78] => 13
                [79] => 5
                [80] => 5
                [81] => 10
                [82] => 25
                [83] => 14
                [84] => 3
                [85] => 25
                [86] => 12
                [87] => 19
                [88] => 5
                [89] => 35
                [90] => 23
                [91] => 5
                [92] => 55
                [93] => 30
                [94] => 10
                [95] => 55
                [96] => 7
                [97] => 40
                [98] => 20
                [99] => 3
                [100] => 3
            )

        [plan_ruc] => Array
            (
                [0] => 242767,5
                [1] => 178041,4
                [2] => 368117,1
                [3] => 476980
                [4] => 615448
                [5] => 1140144,5
                [6] => 315642
                [7] => 1209201
                [8] => 73789
                [9] => 139579
                [10] => 78644,15
                [11] => 221751
                [12] => 134701,5
                [13] => 0
                [14] => 35912,44
                [15] => 22171,8
                [16] => 16164,48
                [17] => 52576,04
                [18] => 21704
                [19] => 0
                [20] => 27644,24
                [21] => 23113,6
                [22] => 12705,55
                [23] => 8458,8
                [24] => 70815,6
                [25] => 224357
                [26] => 47777,1
                [27] => 989401,5
                [28] => 124591,3
                [29] => 50191,4
                [30] => 614400
                [31] => 785022
                [32] => 45368,55
                [33] => 216780
                [34] => 261502,7
                [35] => 92602,5
                [36] => 87209,5
                [37] => 3857,61
                [38] => 73290,1
                [39] => 38290,8
                [40] => 2810,24
                [41] => 165571
                [42] => 73618,4
                [43] => 21832,92
                [44] => 11338,11
                [45] => 29758,35
                [46] => 20311,12
                [47] => 26299,68
                [48] => 13356,5
                [49] => 5317,53
                [50] => 68941,6
                [51] => 151840
                [52] => 464390,4
                [53] => 396558,8
                [54] => 74321,16
                [55] => 455810,4
                [56] => 443031,92
                [57] => 5564,46
                [58] => 109182,6
                [59] => 572609,64
                [60] => 310613,94
                [61] => 317438,1
                [62] => 157799,5
                [63] => 127727,38
                [64] => 110044,4
                [65] => 1083651
                [66] => 145196,4
                [67] => 60130,2
                [68] => 82039,75
                [69] => 28839,92
                [70] => 86387,42
                [71] => 210851,82
                [72] => 35080,78
                [73] => 41883,52
                [74] => 101046,65
                [75] => 82370,9
                [76] => 13975
                [77] => 9264,15
                [78] => 7837,7
                [79] => 5826,1
                [80] => 5713,75
                [81] => 8766,1
                [82] => 10812,75
                [83] => 9179,94
                [84] => 2968,47
                [85] => 10812,75
                [86] => 5969,64
                [87] => 9751,94
                [88] => 4541,7
                [89] => 24215,45
                [90] => 14270,58
                [91] => 5301,5
                [92] => 108743,8
                [93] => 62888,4
                [94] => 26870,8
                [95] => 183850,15
                [96] => 26504,03
                [97] => 212363,6
                [98] => 138934,8
                [99] => 12753,54
                [100] => 19055,94
            )

        [stvarna_kolicina] => Array
            (
                [0] => 414.00
                [1] => 330.00
                [2] => 490.00
                [3] => 690.00
                [4] => 770.00
                [5] => 126.00
                [6] => 1118.00
                [7] => 988.00
                [8] => 41.00
                [9] => 52.00
                [10] => 66.00
                [11] => 126.00
                [12] => 66.00
                [13] => 58.00
                [14] => 56.00
                [15] => 10.00
                [16] => 46.00
                [17] => 36.00
                [18] => 77.00
                [19] => 0
                [20] => 36.00
                [21] => 19.00
                [22] => 51.00
                [23] => 18.00
                [24] => 267.00
                [25] => 707.00
                [26] => 99.00
                [27] => 1345.00
                [28] => 168.00
                [29] => 63.00
                [30] => 0
                [31] => 693.00
                [32] => 41.00
                [33] => 144.00
                [34] => 168.00
                [35] => 50.00
                [36] => 70.00
                [37] => 0
                [38] => 130.00
                [39] => 0
                [40] => 3.00
                [41] => 310.00
                [42] => 107.00
                [43] => 17.00
                [44] => 6.00
                [45] => 14.00
                [46] => 8.00
                [47] => 16.00
                [48] => 12.00
                [49] => 17.00
                [50] => 277.00
                [51] => 438.00
                [52] => 0
                [53] => 0
                [54] => 363.00
                [55] => 0
                [56] => 0
                [57] => 0
                [58] => 0
                [59] => 0
                [60] => 181.00
                [61] => 0
                [62] => 0
                [63] => 0
                [64] => 0
                [65] => 123.00
                [66] => 12.00
                [67] => 0
                [68] => 0
                [69] => 0
                [70] => 0
                [71] => 1.00
                [72] => 0
                [73] => 0
                [74] => 3.00
                [75] => 18.00
                [76] => 11.00
                [77] => 1.00
                [78] => 5.00
                [79] => 0
                [80] => 0
                [81] => 5.00
                [82] => 0
                [83] => 0
                [84] => 0
                [85] => 5.00
                [86] => 4.00
                [87] => 5.00
                [88] => 0
                [89] => 4.00
                [90] => 17.00
                [91] => 5.00
                [92] => 23.00
                [93] => 0
                [94] => 0
                [95] => 26.00
                [96] => 4.00
                [97] => 27.00
                [98] => 8.00
                [99] => 0
                [100] => 2.00
            )

        [stvarni_ruc] => Array
            (
                [0] => 145648.76
                [1] => 157115.52
                [2] => 244852.53
                [3] => 438931.48
                [4] => 572497.62
                [5] => 122336.09
                [6] => 1049849.74
                [7] => 1119343.54
                [8] => 59237.84
                [9] => 68106.98
                [10] => 96078.64
                [11] => 176842.83
                [12] => 118581.00
                [13] => 99181.28
                [14] => 34401.46
                [15] => 11262.95
                [16] => 16970.98
                [17] => 49393.38
                [18] => 19029.19
                [19] => 0
                [20] => 30884.49
                [21] => 20906.26
                [22] => 13078.78
                [23] => 6966.74
                [24] => 74009.55
                [25] => 305741.74
                [26] => 47103.27
                [27] => 821475.24
                [28] => 129386.56
                [29] => 44850.82
                [30] => 0
                [31] => 667621.28
                [32] => 42625.27
                [33] => 214145.26
                [34] => 220182.31
                [35] => 94638.87
                [36] => 90331.17
                [37] => 0
                [38] => 71034.51
                [39] => 0
                [40] => 3867.54
                [41] => 163295.92
                [42] => 69369.88
                [43] => 23763.83
                [44] => 9882.22
                [45] => 29686.98
                [46] => 20789.23
                [47] => 26490.86
                [48] => 15855.51
                [49] => 4800.25
                [50] => 131020.87
                [51] => 248612.27
                [52] => 0
                [53] => 0
                [54] => 341099.80
                [55] => 0
                [56] => 0
                [57] => 0
                [58] => 0
                [59] => 0
                [60] => 729290.05
                [61] => 0
                [62] => 0
                [63] => 0
                [64] => 0
                [65] => 838369.61
                [66] => 105917.94
                [67] => 0
                [68] => 0
                [69] => 0
                [70] => 0
                [71] => 24487.98
                [72] => 0
                [73] => 0
                [74] => 63398.74
                [75] => 142510.58
                [76] => 6123.60
                [77] => 1249.38
                [78] => 4682.50
                [79] => 0
                [80] => 0
                [81] => 5915.67
                [82] => 0
                [83] => 0
                [84] => 0
                [85] => 2341.71
                [86] => 2670.71
                [87] => 3864.25
                [88] => 0
                [89] => 3030.76
                [90] => 11855.71
                [91] => 6289.68
                [92] => 42620.48
                [93] => 0
                [94] => 0
                [95] => 89556.44
                [96] => 16532.85
                [97] => 160561.48
                [98] => 44517.85
                [99] => 0
                [100] => 13012.87
                [101] => 0
                [102] => 0
                [103] => 2733038.88
                [104] => 908686.44
                [105] => 2459420.03
                [106] => 300767.19
                [107] => 383612.96
                [108] => 82092.06
                [109] => 171824.31
                [110] => 7405.99                    
            )

    )
```

)

Desired output:

```
array (
      [article_no] => 967 86 19-03
      [planirana_kol] => 100
      [planirani_ruc] => 1243,56
      [stvarna_kol] => 142
      [stvarni_ruc] => 874,54
 )
array (
      [article_no] => 967 10 84-01
      [planirana_kol] => 300
      [planirani_ruc] => 567,56
      [stvarna_kol] => 284
      [stvarni_ruc] => 777,54
 )
```

Can you point me to a right direction? I'm just stuck with this and I can't get out of it.

Comment: Explain the nature of values from `planirana_kol` and others indexes

Comment: your HTML is invalid btw! You cannot straddle parts of the table as the form does here. The form MUST wholly contain the table or be wholly contained within a single table cell to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild your form as:

```
<form class="posalji_podatke" name="posalji_podatke[]" method="post" action="store_projection.php">
<tr>
   <td><div class="article_no"> <input type="hidden" class="article_no" name="freez[0][article_no]" value="'.$value['article_no'].'"> '.$value['article_no'].'</div></td>
   <td>'.$naziv.'</td>
   <td><div class="plan_kolicina"> <input type="hidden" class="planska_kolicina" name="freez[0][plan_kolicina]" value="'.$plan_kolicina.'"> '.$plan_kolicina.'</div></td>
   <td><div class="plan_ruc"> <input type="hidden" class="planska_ruc" name="freez[0][plan_ruc]" value="'.$plan_ruc.'"> '.myNumberFormat($plan_ruc).'</div> kn</td>
   <td>'.myNumberFormat($plan_ruc_per).' %</td>
   <td><div class="prodana_kol"> <input type="hidden" class="stvarna_kolicina" name="freez[0][stvarna_kolicina]" value="'.$kolicina.'"> '.$kolicina.'</div></td>
   <td><div class="prodani_ruc"> <input type="hidden" class="stvarni_ruc" name="freez[0][stvarni_ruc]" value="'.$realizacija_ruc.'"> '.myNumberFormat($realizacija_ruc).'</div> kn</td>
   <td>'.myNumberFormat($realizacija_ruc_per).' %</td>
```

Note that I `name`d your inputs as `name="freez[0][article_no]"`.

Also you need to set indexes **explicitly**, i.e.:

```
name="freez[0][article_no]"
name="freez[1][article_no]"
name="freez[2][article_no]"
// etc
// NOT name="freez[][article_no]"
```

With such `input` naming your `$_POST` array will be of the required structure.

Comment: That's exactly it! You saved my day. I was doing it completely wrong on the HTML form. I used freez[article_no]['.$i.'] and thats what threw me off. I couldn't get out of it and change places. Thank you so much for pointing me to a right direction!!!